# Home equity loan against foreign property

Tags: united-states, mortgage, canada, home-loan, home-equity

I'm a United States citizen and own a house in Canada.  I have a clean title and the entire house is paid off.

Is it legal for any United States banks to give home equity loans against this foreign property?

Comment: Even if it were _legal_ (whether or not it is is a question for law.SE,not money.SE), you will likely find it difficult to find a bank willing to give a home equity loan against a property that the bank will have difficulty foreclosing on in the event that you default on the loan. Why make _you_ a home equity loan when there are plenty of customers with properties in the US who are seeking home equity loans?

Comment: As @DilipSarwate said - I tried this, and no bank was willing to give me a loan based on that. I found a bank in Europe that gave me a loan against my US house that I was buying, and in the US, I could use that money as cash downpayment (as the US bank not only ignores equity outside of the US, but also debts!)